# Join JS String Array and JSX element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to join `"8.8.8.8".split('.')` JS Array of elements with JSX element `<span className="bullet">•</span>`.

Rendering this in the React environment gives `8[object Object]8[object Object]8[object Object]8`.

Any solution to this ?

Comment: whats your expected output?

Comment: 8 • 8 • 8 • 8 @ashishsingh

Comment: dot is html element is it ?

Comment: @ashishsingh yes. It is <span className="bullet">•</span>

Comment: but its not string its a JSX element and hence its doing it

Comment: Should I map the array to JSX element then ?

Comment: yes that is absolutely right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it

```
"8.8.8.8".split('.').reduce((res, item) => {
    if (!res) {
        return [item];
    }

    return [...res, <span className="bullet">•</span>, item];
})
```

Comment: You don't actually need `if (!res) { return [item]; }`

Comment: Why? It is required for initialize first element

Comment: I'm pretty sure '8' is the first element. No?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to loop and then render a span with a bullet per iteration.

I am also going to assume you want a span so it is an inline element?

I would not use the character bullet, but rather use something like:

```
<ul>
    // loop through your array here
    <li className="bullet" style="display:inline;"> 
         arrayElement 
    </li>
</ul>
```

alternatively, if you MUST use a bullet point, just specify the actual code for the bullet rather then the symbol

• (Circular Bullet Point) code:   `& #8226;` or `& bull;`

Answer (score 0):

Since this is for React, it can be done like this.

In your Component:

```
render(){
    let myArray = "8.8.8.8".split('.');

    return (
    <div>
      {myArray.map((item, index) => {
        if (index !== myArray.length -1 ) {
            return <span key={index}>{item}<span className="bullet">•</span></span>
           } else {
            return <span key={index}>{item}</span>
           }
         })}
    </div>
    );
}
```

Basically what is being done here is:

- Create the array (or get it from other function).
- Loop over the array items.
- Create a span object for the numbers and the dot, except for the last one.
- All being done in the render of the component.

Result is:

```
8•8•8•8
```

In html:

```
<div>
    <span>8<span class="bullet">•</span></span>
    <span>8<span class="bullet">•</span></span>
    <span>8<span class="bullet">•</span></span>
    <span>8</span>
</div>
```

Here's a [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pm6rj7llnj) to see it working.

You could receive the array as props of the component as well and create a static component to always render something similar.

remove:

```
let myArray = "8.8.8.8".split('.');
```

change

```
myArray.map
```

to

```
this.props.myArray.map
```

call like this:

```
<NumberDotComponent myArray={"8.8.8.8".split('.')}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `join` tries to convert the object (React element) to a string, since join is a string function.  `[object Object]` is the result of the `toString` method on that object.  Instead, you should return an array.

Here's an example that iterates over each character of the string and replaces a specific character with a React element:

```js
function App(props) {
  let foo = '8.8.8.8'
  let replaceChar = '.'
  let output = [...foo].map(char=>(
    char === replaceChar ? <span className="bullet">•</span> : char
  ))
  
  return <React.Fragment>{output}</React.Fragment>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha256-3NNU/yoE0R7VxxapKiw/hkgQzcSMztyclb5RpeVlV7Y=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="app">Error Encountered</div>
```